# If p is prime and $\gcd(a,p-1)=1$ then $x^{1/a}=x^{-a}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ where $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of a in $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, radicals

I need to prove the following.

If p is prime and $\gcd(a,p-1)=1$ then $b^{1/a}=b^{-a}$ exists for any $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ where $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$

I know $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is a cyclic group with $p-1$ elements. I think that, as a result, each $b$ has a distinct root of any degree, but I don't know how to show that for sure and I'm not sure how $a^{-1}$ being the inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ would come into things.

Comment: I doubt that $b^{1/a} = b^{-a}$ in general. For example let $a = 1$ and $b \neq b^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$, and let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(a, p - 1) = 1$.

Then by Euler's theorem we have $a^{\varphi(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod {p-1}$.

Then $\left(b^{a^{\varphi(p-1)-1}}\right)^a = b^{a^{\varphi(p-1)}} \equiv b \pmod p$ so $b$ is a perfect $a$-th power.

Comment: In fact it's also true for any $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ since $0$ is obviously a perfect $a$-th power for any $a \gt 0$.

Comment: Why is $b^{a^{\varphi(p-1)}} \equiv b \pmod p$? I don't remember learning a rule about a powers working that way.

Comment: @chris I am using Euler's theorem again (or Fermat's little theorem in that particular case), that $b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. I showed above that $a^{\varphi(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod {p-1}$ so that means $a^{\varphi(p-1)} = 1 + k(p-1)$ for some integer $k$. Then $b^{a^{\varphi(p-1)}} = b^{1 + k(p-1)} = b \left(b^{p-1}\right)^k \equiv b \pmod p$.